Vite HMR stops working when removing imported css file
I'm trying out Vite with just HTML/CSS/TS and trying to understand the behavior of HMR. I created the project using pnpm create vite, and have two relevant files which I've modified a bit:
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>

main.ts
import './main.css'

let text: HTMLHeadingElement = document.createElement('h1');
text.innerHTML = 'Hello world';
document.body.appendChild(text);

main.css is just an empty file
When I modify the innerHTML in main.ts and then save the change, I get a vite page reload message in the terminal and the text automatically updates in the browser (in other words a successful HMR). Removing the seemingly meaningless import statement in the file however still produces the same message in the terminal after modifying the text and saving, but the change isn't reflected in the browser until I manually refresh it. Why is it that removing the import statement causes HMR to break? I suspect that it has something to do with dependencies or that I haven't configured something I should be, but can't figure out why it's behaving this way. I tried seeing if I got the same effect by just importing an empty test.ts file instead, but this has the same behaviour as not importing anything at all.

Cannot reproduce. Consider adding a [mre]
